# How many factors of $2400$ are not factors of $3600$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, factoring

I solved this question by writing all the factors and then just selecting the factors as per the question requirement.

But I want to know is there any other way to solve this? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I would factor them and look at exponents of the primes of 2400 that are larger than those of of the same primes that are factors of 3600.

Comment: Expanding on David's comment: take advantage of the fact that choosing a factor is equivalent to choosing how many of each prime factor you want, from zero up to the power in the factorization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a prime number decomposition you find

$$2400 = 2^5\cdot 3 \cdot 5^2$$
$$3600 = 2^4\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2$$

So the only time you can have a factor of $2400$ and not of $3600$ is when $2^5=32$ divides it.

Thus, the factors are
$$ 32=2^5$$
$$ 96=2^5 \cdot 3$$
$$ 480=2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$$
$$ 160=2^5 \cdot 5$$
$$ 800=2^5 \cdot 5^2$$
$$ 2400=2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^2$$

Comment: Note for the general case, instead of listing them we can just conclude that since there are $2$ options of a power for $3$ and $3$ options of a power for $5,$ that there must be $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ such factors.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Umm.. I am sorry but I am not able to understand the solution. Can you please explain a little the concept when you mentioned "So the only time you can have a factor of $2400 $ and not of $3600$ is when $2^5=32$ divides it."?

Comment: If you look at the prime number decomposition, you can easily see all the factors of a number. So, if for example I would take $15 =3 \cdot 5$ as one subset of the factors of $2400$, I know that this will divide $2400=(3 \cdot 5) \cdot (2^5\cdot 5)$. Unfortunately, $3\cdot 5$ is also present in the prime number decomposition of $3600=(3\cdot 5)\cdot (2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5)$ so this does not help us. The only minimal factor that is not present in $3600$ is $2^5$ and thus, all other factors have to have this one in it.

Comment: got it . This was really helpful. Thanks !

Comment: @Ganit Awesome to hear. Glad I could help :)